# How to pass a lambda-function with generic arguments as parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, generics, lambda

I can't understand how can I use lambda with generic arguments and pass it as parameter in another method.
Below my code that I have now (wrong, of course):

```
class Arrays final
{
public:    
    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertionSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
        auto func = [](RandomIt lt, RandomIt rt) {
            return *lt > (*rt);
        };
        InsertSort(first, last, func);
    }

    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertionSortDesc(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
        auto func = [](RandomIt lt, RandomIt rt) {
            return *lt < (*rt);
        };
        InsertSort(first, last, func);
    }

private:
    Arrays();

    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last,
                         std::function<bool (RandomIt, RandomIt)> func) {
        int length = std::distance(first, last);

        if (length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        RandomIt j = first + 1;

        for (; j != last; ++j) {
            auto key = *j;
            RandomIt i = j - 1;

            while (i >= first && func(i, j)) {
                *(i + 1) = (*i);
                --i;
            }

            *(++i) = key;
        }
    }
};
```

It crashes in the compile time with errors:

```
arrays.h:38: error: no matching function for call to 'Arrays::InsertSort(const int*&, const int*&, Arrays::InsertionSort(RandomIt, RandomIt) [with RandomIt = const int*]::<lambda(const int*, const int*)>&)'
         InsertSort(first, last, func);
                   ^
```

How to write it correctly? Is it possible in C++ v11?

Comment: To be honest, I would change `InsertSort` to be `template <class RandomIt, class Compare> static void InsertSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare && func) { ...`. There is no reason to require the argument to be an `std::function` instance; any suitable callable should do.

Comment: @cdhowie, sorry, Imma noobie in C++. But I don't see in this declaration any check of argument types of function i.e I can pass a wrong function (with other arguments)? Will it crash in the compile time in this case?

Comment: Yes, if you pass a callable where the arguments can't be converted, the template will fail to instantiate.

Comment: @cdhowie, I tried your solution and got a new error: `arrays.h:67: ошибка: assignment of read-only location '*(i + 4u)'
                 *(i + 1) = (*i);
                          ^`

Comment: Well, based on the compiler error in your question, you are passing in a `const int *` (pointer to *constant* int), so what did you expect? Show the code where you call `Arrays::InsertionSort()`.

Comment: @cdhowie, sorry, I fooled... Yeah, you're right, of course. I passed `const` array.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I have NOT tested your code. However, the following compiles. The function is static therefore its declaration must come in ORDER of usage. To fix it, move the declaration of `InsertSort` before all other functions that use it. Next, you need to call `InsertSort` with the template parameter.

Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Arrays final
{
private:
    Arrays();

    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last,
                           std::function<bool (RandomIt, RandomIt)> func) {
        auto length = std::distance(first, last);

        if (length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        RandomIt j = first + 1;


        for (; j != last; ++j) {
            auto key = *j;
            RandomIt i = j - 1;

            while (i >= first && func(i, j)) {
                *(i + 1) = (*i);
                --i;
            }

            *(++i) = key;
        }
    }

public:
    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertionSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
        auto func = [](RandomIt lt, RandomIt rt) {
            return *lt > (*rt);
        };
        InsertSort<RandomIt>(first, last, func);
    }

    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertionSortDesc(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
        auto func = [](RandomIt lt, RandomIt rt) {
            return *lt < (*rt);
        };
        InsertSort<RandomIt>(first, last, func);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 9, 4, 5, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7};

    Arrays::InsertionSort(vec.begin(), vec.end());


    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    }

    std::cout<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As noted in a comment :D You don't have to change the declaration order if you qualify the call to the function..

Ex:  `Arrays::InsertSort<RandomIt>(....);`

```
class Arrays final
{
public:
    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertionSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
        auto func = [](RandomIt lt, RandomIt rt) {
            return *lt > (*rt);
        };
        Arrays::InsertSort<RandomIt>(first, last, func);
    }

    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertionSortDesc(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
        auto func = [](RandomIt lt, RandomIt rt) {
            return *lt < (*rt);
        };
        Arrays::InsertSort<RandomIt>(first, last, func);
    }

private:
    Arrays();

    template<class RandomIt>
    static void InsertSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last,
                           std::function<bool (RandomIt, RandomIt)> func) {
        auto length = std::distance(first, last);

        if (length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        RandomIt j = first + 1;

        for (; j != last; ++j) {
            auto key = *j;
            RandomIt i = j - 1;

            while (i >= first && func(i, j)) {
                *(i + 1) = (*i);
                --i;
            }

            *(++i) = key;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't have to declare one before the other *if* you qualify the call with the class name (`Arrays::InsertSort`). Or, at least G++ accepts the code if the call site qualifies the name.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for answer and comments! You helped me very much!